# Detail Page Case Button to update a status field value

Tags: administration

Is there any way to create a custom button with URL or Javascript, and the scenario is when a user click on custom button(edit button functionality) in case object it should pre-populate the status field value to '**NEW**' even it is having different status. I tried by using button URL, but I dint find where can I find status ID?Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks In Advance:
Naresh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below screenshot will tell you how to use inspect element and get the Id and then how to append and form URL to pre-populate

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

> Please note this is risky if salesforce changes the IDs of these element and hence this method should be avoided .Instead try using the solution described in below blogs for same

http://www.frankneezen.com/2013/04/salesforce-url-hacking-prepopulating-fields/
http://andyinthecloud.com/2014/01/05/querying-custom-object-and-field-ids-via-tooling-api/

Comment: This is actual standard edit button URL: https://cs15.salesforce.com/500e0000002W9KK/e?retURL=%2F500e0000002W9KK. Here 500e0000002W9KK, it is particular case record ID, but I dint figure out how can I get 15 digit standard case object ID.?